# html: iframe scale to fit except for top line

Tags: html, css, iframe, scale

I am trying to make a scale to fit iframe, except for a top line with a warning. For example:

```
<div style="text-align:center">Warning! blabla</div>
<iframe src="link" style="width:100%; height: 100%; transform-scale" frameborder = "0"></iframe>

<style>
    html, body, #wrapper{
        width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is that if I do it like that the last line on the bottom of the iframe gets cut off, and scrolling isn't possible.

Comment: Have you tried with `height: auto` and removing the `overflow:hidden`? I have noticed also that `#wrapper` is not applied to iframe.

Comment: @emmanuel Hey I tried your solution. I can scroll the background behind iframe, but it is not good solution, because the content of iframe itself is scroll-able too so now i have 2 scroll-boxes, with  more or less same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc()` to calculate the height of the iframe.
To do this, you have to set a height for your warning:

```
<div style="text-align:center; height: 50px;">Warning! blabla</div>
```

Then you can set the height of your iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="link" style="width:100%; height: calc(100% - 50px); ... ></iframe>
```

Read more about `calc()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: hmm interesting answer. Problem is that warning is dynamic and might take more than 50px. probably i should have mentioned that b4 :// srry

Comment: You maybe have to use Javscript/Jquery to solve this.

Comment: yeah ://. thing is im trying to keep it simple so it works mobile browsers too.

Comment: You have to define a fixed height (10% is also "fix") or use Javascript (that works also in mobile browsers)

Comment: 50px was just an example, it should be the height of the warning div.

Comment: So I guess div height should be auto then. Is there a way to get height = whatsleft of page. or height = calc(100% - div.height)?

Comment: I think that's only possible in Javascript

Comment: According to the documentation this experimental. "This is an experimental technology".

Answer (score 0):

Use the following style:

```
iframe {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

And then with javascript you can change the "top" style depending on how much place you need on the top.